# Spark SQL :Job aborted due to stage failure: java.io.InvalidClassException: SpecificMutableRow; local class incompatible

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, hivecontext

I was trying to retrieve hive tables from Spark scala (Both Hive Cluster , spark cluster and my local system have same JDK version 8)

```
 var tableData= objHiveContext.hql("select * from intervalmeterdemandbymonth  c")
 println(tableData)  //Line1
 var rowData = tableData.collect()
 println(rowData)`
```

I was able to print table columns with Line 1
but while trying to exec collect statement  due to **serialVersionUID i.e incompatible class path**

`WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, SERVERIP): **java.io.InvalidClassException**: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.SpecificMutableRow; **local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -2362733443263122426, local class serialVersionUID = -8202316371712574867**
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:621)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1623)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1801)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1707)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1345)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1993)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1918)`

Comment: So... is there a question somewhere?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I'm Unable to retrieve data (or loop through it ), how can I read my data form object tableData after loading from hivecontext , I'm getting above exceptipon.

Comment: I suggest that you search StackOverflow for keywords `InvalidClassException serialVersionUID` and also that you search the Spark JIRAs for bugs affecting your version (that you did not care to mention). Good luck. Sounds like a nasty Java config / compilation issue.

Comment: Unable to resolve the issue mentioned @SerialVersionUID(23L) attribute to my object with various trial and error but couldn't get. Using Hadoop Version :2.7.1 Spark:1.4.1, Scala Version 2.10.4 In my pom.xml I have <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId> <version>1.4.1</version> </dependency